# Spring Boot: How to use multiple schemas and dynamically choose which one to use for every request at runtime

Tags: java, database-design, spring-boot

Premise:
I chose to do this because I might end up having a few thousand schemas, each having (amongst others) 1 table with a few million entries. The alternative was having (amongst others) one table with a few billion entries in one schema.

The best way to elaborate on this question is providing a simple example. Consider the following:

User.java

```
@Entity(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

UserDao.java

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {}
```

UserService.java

```
public interface UserService {
    User getUser(Long id);
}
```

UserServiceBean.java

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class UserServiceBean implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserDao dao;

    @Override
    public User getUser(Long id) {
        return dao.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

UserController.java

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/api/users/{id}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(
            @PathVariable("id") Long id) {

        User user = userService.getUser(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I would like to extend to the following functionality: supplying another ID in the URL in order to return user data from a different table.

UserController.java

```
...
@RequestMapping(
            value = "/api/users/{id}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(
            @PathVariable("id") Long id,
            @RequestParam(value = "tlbid") Long tblId) {

        User user = userService.getUser(id, tblId);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Now the UserService will decode that ID into something that could be useful for spring in order to get the data from a different table.

UserServiceBean.java

```
    ...
    public User getUser(Long id, Long tblId) {
        Object o = doMagic(tblId);
        // What should 'o' be and how could I use this?
    }
```

All the tables have the same structure and names but different entries. The tables have to be on a different database, or in the same database but on a different schema.

I would like to know either:

a) How can I have one database connection and specify a different schema for every request.

b) How to create new database connections when necessary (I would maintain them for further requests), and specify on which connection should the request be made each time.

c) My premises are wrong and having billions of entries in a table and high concurrency does not significantly slow down query speeds.

Comment: I kind of think it's c). You should in either case probably not leak your attempts at database partitioning into the api. (http://www.paperplanes.de/2011/12/9/the-magic-of-consistent-hashing.html or so might be sth for you)

Comment: I am worried that such a table will be automatically re-organized many times while it's growing (for efficient hashing) and that concurrent changes will make it slow.

Comment: One billion-row table is better than 1K million-row tables.

Comment: hi Alin, could you solve your problem? I am looking for a solution for the same problem.

Comment: Hi @Irtaza. I opted to not go this route anymore, based on Rick James' answer. This was a college project and with the wisdom gained 4 years later I am happy I decided to not add any more complexity and use a single table.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're describing a multi-tenant solution. See [the Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy) for a longer description and a few options for how you could partition your data.

Note: we are trying to implement the schema-based multi-tenant approach at the moment :)

Comment: This answer points in right direction instead of just showing the work around.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are using hibernate entity class then you can always use different schemas for same datasource provided that the other schemas are accessible for the particular user mapped in Datasource.

you can use `schema` attribute of `Table` annotation in your entity class. Use the below syntax for using different schema

`@Table(name="TABLE_NAME",schema="SCHEMA2")`

Comment: The question here is how the schema name can be "dynamically" changed/switched to access the tables with the same structure. This purpose can't be solved by simply hardcoding the schema name in the entity.