# Can I use JPA without database name in config

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Can I use the database without the database name with JPA?

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307

Answer (score 1):

No. You will get the error "No database selected". 
What do you want to accomplish with this?

Comment: I wan to use different schema in the same database, without defining two different connection.

Comment: You can declare multiple db names and then choose which to use. check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179442/spring-boot-how-to-use-multiple-schemas-and-dynamically-choose-which-one-to-use/42360877

If you do not give us more info we cannot help you much more...